Considering 96 observation for estimating the intercept (rule of thumb)
I remember Prof. Frank Harrell stated that in order to calculate the sample size using the rule of thumb, we must include 96 observations for just computing the intercept, hence the estimated sample size is 96+15*the number of parameters.

If I wish to use the rule of thumb for a survival model, do I still need to include 96 observations to compute the intercept?  96+15*the number of parameters

If I wish to use the rule of thumb following Ogundimu et al. advice, considering 20 observations for each parameter in the model, do I still need to include 96 observations to compute sample size?



It will help to understand that behind any rule of thumb lie assumptions about the scope of its applicability and, in statistical applications, assumptions about levels of precision or certainty one would feel are adequate.  That (of course) begs the important questions of context and objectives.  I believe Dr. Harrell's rules of thumb arise in certain biomedical applications, about which I would defer to his expertise; but I do know that in many other circumstances those rules do not necessarily work well.

As I recall, that recommendation for 96 is to get a precise estimate of the intercept (log-odds at reference conditions) in a logistic regression model. If all you care about is how changes in predictors are associated with changes in log odds, you don't need to use that large a sample. See Section 4.4 of Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies for sample-size recommendations in that situation.
A survival model has no intercept at at all, so that's not an issue in your application. To avoid overfitting, the above link suggests 15 events (not observations) per coefficient that you want to estimate in a survival model.
That number might not be enough, however, to have adequate power to detect some treatment-associated difference in outcomes that you hope to find. For that you need to do a more formal power analysis.

Great resource in the Link
